# backwards Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have started to implement backwards Dijkstra's algorithm in python:

```
def backwardsDijkstra(g: DoubleDictGraph, s, t):
    q = PriorityQueue()
    dist = {}
    next = {}
    q.add(t, 0)
    dist[t] = 0
    found = False
    while not q.isEmpty() and not found:
        x = q.pop()
        for y in g.parseNin(x):
            if y not in dist.keys() or dist[x] + g.Cost(x, y) < dist[y]:
                dist[y] = dist[x] + g.Cost(x, y)
                q.add(y, dist[y])
                next[y] = x
        if x == t:
            found = True
    return dist[s], next
```

And I can't figure out why it stops at the second iteration for the next graph for example:

```
5 7
0 1 5
0 2 20
1 2 10
1 3 30
2 3 5
2 4 20
3 4 10
(number of vertices, number of edges, (start,end,cost)
```

Comment: Why are you checking for target? `if x == t:  found = True`. Shouldn't you be checking for source?

Answer (score 0):

The bug in you code is at this line:

```
        if x == t:
            found = True
```

Since you are starting from `t` (target), you should be looking for `s` (source). Currently you are breaking out of the loop for the first candidate (which is t).